# Integer.parseInt() throws "For input string: XXX"

Tags: java, math

I am reading high volume of records from a csv file. 
one of the column is amount and it has 2 decimal places.
So I wanted to parse it to integer form but it hit error when come to this as below :

```
int trxnAmt = Integer.parseInt("002428859600");
```

Suppose it will be 2428859600 right ?

but it throws me error > java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "002428859600"

I tried to use :

```
long a = Long.parseLong("002428859600");
```

it worked fine for me .

I still cannot find out what's going on. Is the number too big ?

Comment: `Integer.MAX_VALUE = 0x7fffffff` - your number is 90c574d0, so yes: It's too big for an Integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes `2428859600` is a long number. try to assign it a int and you'd get a compiler error :

```
int i = 2428859600;  // error as 2428859600 is clearly outta int range(2,147,483,647)
long l = 2428859600L; //no error
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are passing out of the range integer value to `parseInt` method.

> The int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer. It has
>   a minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of **2,147,483,647**
>   (inclusive).

Try long or other suitable options.
This might help you : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 1):

> Is the number too big?

Yes. An `int` is 4 bytes, so the biggest number that will fit into an `int` is 2<sup>4*8-1</sup>-1 = 2<sup>31</sup>-1 = 2147483647 (4*8-1 because 1 bit is required for sign).

See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Answer (score -1):

You should make sure that your input really is an integer (i.e. "16"), or if it's out of Integer range, then use `Double.parseDouble()` or `Long.parseLong()`

Answer (score -1):

You are getting the `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "002428859600"` because, the number `002428859600` cannot be represented as a 32-bit integer (type `int`). It can be represented as a 64-bit integer (type `long`). long literals in Java end with an "L": `002428859600L`

Comment: That long literals end with an "L" does not have anything to do with the problem. The number in the string is not a number literal.

Comment: I did not mean that you can try Integer.parseInt("002428859600L"); to resolve the problem. I just mentioned the root cause of the exception. If you will get the same exception if you try with Integer.parseInt("002428859600L"); You have misinterpreted I guess...

Comment: The first sentence of your answer is correct; 2428859600 doesn't fit in a 32-bit signed `int`. But why do you mention that long literals end with an "L"? That's also true, but is totally irrelevant for the problem.

Comment: @SarathKumarSivan Note that `L` is not a valid character for `parseInt`, `Integer.parseInt("123L")` throws a `NumberFormatException`.